# SQL Server Key value pairs

Tags: sql-server

Ok I have stupid table that was inherited there are 3 fields that I need to break up into a key value pair.  The data is as below.

UserID:  001

Keys:    CompanyID:0:1:FirstName:1:4:LastName:5:6:ExtranetID:11:5:Company:16:3:Application:0:-1:

Values:
3ZachTaylor11057XYZ

As you can see the keys hold a substring value for the values to be split with.  Also the caveat is if the length is -1 then the value is null or blank.

How do I make a sql function to break this up so I can get everything properly in key value pairs.

Comment: Will there be always 6 key/value pairs?

Comment: Does it have to be a SQL function? It feels like you may be better off reading the data into some other programming language that's better at string manipulation to clean it up. How much data have you got like this?

Comment: If you will always have the same key value pairs, and know the max limit, you can split it up using the substring function and pattern recognition for your key names. If the number of keys or which keys are present is not consistent then you would be better off splitting this with the substring function but throwing it into a nosql database.

Comment: OMG that is one the most hideous "designs" I have ever seen. Does that person who handed this to you still work there? That is just awful. Since you always have the same key-value pairs maybe moving to a table with 6 columns would make sense and abandon the concept of key-value?

Comment: No they aren't here anymore.  I have no idea why they just didnt put the key value pair in one field and seperate each pair by a ; and each key value by the :
We are doing it through code, but if we can we would like to query the information to see what is wrong.

Comment: Do you always have those exact 6 keys? Some table definition and a few rows of sample data would help considerably here.